# iterating dictionary in a for loop too many times?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that returns a list of keys with the highest values in a dictionary, limited to a defined range. I don't understand why the following code produces a list longer than the defined range...

I'm a self-teaching python noob. I've tried surfing other SO helppages, but nothing I've found seems to help. I've tried tweaking whatever I can in the code below, and I could possibly come up with a different approach entirely, but I just don't understand WHY IT DOESN'T WORK?

```
def foo(somedict, number):
    mylist = somedict.values()
    for x in range(number):
        for letter in somedict:
            if somedict[letter] == max(mylist):
                print letter
                mylist.remove(max(mylist))
```

I expected the file to be length (number) - in the above example, 3. But it's longer - at least 5.

```
mydict = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}
>>> foo(mydict,3)
d
c
b
a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    foo(mydict,3)
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 5, in foo
    if somedict[letter] == max(mylist):
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Comment: Well, one probable cause of error is your indentation. Python **is** sensitive to indentation levels!

Comment: You're editing a list to remove items in a loop. What happens when you empty the list after deleting all the contents?

Comment: `mylist.remove` is removing values from the list, not the dictionary itself.

Comment: try printing out `somedict` and `mylist` in your loop, will help you see what's happening

Comment: Thanks, Reedinationer. not sure how that happened! acushner, still doesn't help me... I want to know *why* the iteration is being called more times than the range I gave...

Comment: On a side note, you should not use for loops to do this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivial debugging will show the problem.  Insert a `print` to trace your values:

```
def foo(somedict, number):
    mylist = somedict.values()
    for x in range(number):
        for letter in somedict:
            print x, letter, mylist
            if somedict[letter] == max(mylist):
                print letter
                mylist.remove(max(mylist))

mydict = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}
foo(mydict, 3)
```

Output:

```
0 a [1, 3, 2, 4]
0 c [1, 3, 2, 4]
0 b [1, 3, 2, 4]
0 d [1, 3, 2, 4]
d
1 a [1, 3, 2]
1 c [1, 3, 2]
c
1 b [1, 2]
b
1 d [1]
2 a [1]
a
2 c []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 11, in <module>
    foo(mydict, 3)
  File "so.py", line 6, in foo
    if somedict[letter] == max(mylist):
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

You systematically remove every value from the list.  Eventually, you have an empty list, which causes `max` to fail.

Since you haven't told us what you're *trying* to accomplish, we can't "fix" the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this instead:

> somedict.pop(letter, None)

But then we will get

> RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

because we you are constantly changing the dict while you are iterate through the dict. You could assign a None to every key that you wanna delete and then you will get what you want with another iteration.

PS: Also it would be nice to have a try, except with the appropriate error message.

Comment: I don't think this function is supposed to change the dict. Are you thinking of putting somedict.items in a heapq? You're skipping some steps.